# Are aggressive attacking and tactical playeing the same?

Tags: tactics, attack, aggressive-play

What's the difference? Both look same to me.

Comment: I think a aggressive is a characteristic of a player, white attacking may a more aptly describe a side in a particular position.

Comment: An aggressive player makes threats. The threats may be of tactical or positional nature. A player who places his pieces aiming at your king may not have any tactics (yet), but it would feel aggressive nonetheless. He may also "threaten" exchanges that favor him greatly. It does not have quite the same feel as winning material or mating, but those are threats that win games just as well.

Comment: Aggressive is a state of mind, tactical is the tools you use

Comment: I think it depends on whether the "tactical" moves involve attacking the opponent's king or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are related, but probably not the same. If you play an opening like the King's Indian you are probably an aggressive, attacking player, but you may rely more on the understanding of the position than on tactical tricks.

Similarly, there are certain types of position where accurate calculation is required but with defensive purposes.

Aggressive and attacking are probably harder to distinguish, though!